# Distribution data from file over TCP/IP using async socket, the data is lost (if a lot of subscribers)

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

Net Developers, I need some help. I am developing network client-server applications using TCP/IP socket technique and C#. I need to distribute the data located in XML file from server application to several subscribers apps: console windows apps and web apps. I wrote server applications using asynchronous calls technique. Everything is working well, but I have problem: if i run a lot of client applications, some data is lost during distribution. I fill like it is TCP/IP buffer overload, because if i run more apps then more data lost, but i am using CallBack method and I'm checking the previous result of sending (I save the result in ***currentAsynchResult*** to check the delivery, but it's not working for me. Here is some code:

Method to send:

```
        static void SendToAll(string _msg)
    {
        foreach (ClientInfo _client in clientList)
        {
            Data msgToSend = new Data();
            msgToSend.cmdCommand = Command.Message;

            if (_client.strName == "Bill")
            {
                try
                {
                    //Fill the info for the message to be send                       
                    msgToSend.strName = "Bill";
                    msgToSend.strMessage = _msg;
                    byte[] byteData = msgToSend.ToByte();

                    currentClient = _client;

                    //Send it to the client 
                    _client.socket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnBroadcast), currentAsynchResult);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
```

CallBack method:

```
        static void OnBroadcast(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar == currentAsynchResult)
        {
            try
            {
                currentClient.socket.EndSend(ar);
            }

            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Using foreach to send the data:

```
        static void StartDistributeXML()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("test.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            SendtToAll(node.Attributes["text"].InnerText);
        }
    }
```

My idea is: 1. to check the CallBack method (may be my example is not correct) 2. To write some buffer for sending. 3. to check details about sent packet (packet size, packet type , etc) - but i do not know how to implement it. Could please suggest me the solution? I am able to provide more code if needed.

Comment: Why are you catching an exception and not doing anything with it?    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            { }

Comment: I tried to catch the exception using Console.Writeline and it's empty. It's not solving the problem. What is your idea?